# Getting the best fit Instance Method in Java

Tags: java, reflection, methods

If I run the following program:

```
class Runit{
    public static void main(String[] argsWut) throws Exception {
        String arg = "what?";
        Class[] parameters = { new Object().getClass() };
        Object[] args = { arg };
        System.out.println("".getClass().getMethod("equals",parameters).invoke("what?",args));
    }
};
```

I get the following on the command line:

```
true
```

On the other hand, if I modify the parameters line a little:

```
class Runit{
    public static void main(String[] argsWut) throws Exception {
        String arg = "what?";
        Class[] parameters = { arg.getClass() }; // changed a little here so it's a bit more dynamic --
        Object[] args = { arg };
        System.out.println("".getClass().getMethod("equals",parameters).invoke("what?",args));
    }
};
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at test.Runit.main(Runit.java:7)
```

From this one example it looks to me as though the `getMethod` method only works with exact parameters. Is there a way to get some form of a "best fit" method? e.g. If an exact match exists, it would return that method, but if no exact match exists, it can return any method that could accept my given arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for `getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29):

> To find a matching method in a class C:  If C declares exactly one
>   public method with the specified name and **exactly the same formal
>   parameter types**, that is the method reflected. If more than one such
>   method is found in C, and one of these methods has a return type that
>   is more specific than any of the others, that method is reflected;
>   otherwise one of the methods is chosen arbitrarily.

(**Emphasis** mine.)

What you are asking for is to have reflection  perform *overload resolution* for you. And apparently it won't. If you really need this functionality, you can either 1) give up on using reflection and invoke the method directly, or 2) if that's not possible, look up the rules for overload resolution in Java (you could start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)), use [`getMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) to determine the available methods, and then perform overload resolution manually. Fun times, I know.

**Edit**: As [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110742/675502) [answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110744/675502) have pointed out, someone has already taken the time to do that for you. Cool!

Comment: Yes, this is a tricky problem to write a generic utility or solution. Assume there n parameters for a method that you trying to find and each parameter can have m choices, meaning the we have to try the class you provided as a parameter of choice, if that doesn't exist then try its super class and so on up the hierarchy. The search space for the solution has m^n possiblities.

Answer (score 5):

You may have better luck with the Apache Commons Lang MethodUtils class, which has a method "invokeMethod" that uses the target arguments for the method to narrow down the appropriate type (i.e., you don't have to tell it the parameter type).

This seems to work:

```
 System.out.println(MethodUtils.invokeMethod("what?", "equals", new Object[] {"what?"}));
```

See javadocs for more details: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in `Commons BeanUtils` Apache library, specifically this method:
http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#getMatchingAccessibleMethod%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5b%5d%29

Hope this helps

Comment: This finds a match, but not the best possible match.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241178/find-best-matching-writemethod-with-java-reflection