# Find best matching writeMethod with Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Commons BeanUtils getMatchingAccessibleMethod finds a match, but not the best possible match.

Consider this simple example:

```
public class TestReflection extends TestCase {

  public static class BeanA {
    private DataX data;
    public BeanA setData(DataX x) {
      System.out.println("setData x");
      return this;
    }
    public BeanA setData(DataY y) {
      System.out.println("setData y");
      return this;
    }
  }

  static class DataX {
  }
  static class DataY extends DataX {
  }
  static class DataZ extends DataY {
  }

  public void testPropertyUtils() {
    try {
      BeanA a = new BeanA();
      System.out.println("--- setters:");
      a.setData(new DataX());
      a.setData(new DataY());
      a.setData(new DataZ());
      System.out.println("--- invokeMethod");
      MethodUtils.invokeMethod(a, "setData", new DataZ());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

(Hint: invokeMethod uses getMatchingAccessibleMethod)

The above code outputs

```
--- setters:
setData x
setData y
setData y
--- invokeMethod
setData x
```

The last line shoud say "setData y" because the best match for calling "setData" with a DataZ object should be the one with DataY in the interface (just like setData(new DataZ()) does).

Is there a way to find the best possible match or do I have to code that myself?

Comment: Additionally, reflection can't be used to find the name of the writeMethod when your setters "return this" for method chaining purposes since java reflection always wants return type void to match the (I think outdated) bean specs. Any ideas on how to get the name of the writeMethod for the invokeMethod call?

Answer (score 2):

I was just curious how does it works in MethodUtils.java, so i looked inside. To determine which method should be used as the best match, every method will gain a cost. To calculate the cost there is a method (with some extra dbg-output):

```
/**
 * Gets the number of steps required needed to turn the source class into the 
 * destination class. This represents the number of steps in the object hierarchy 
 * graph.
 * @param srcClass The source class
 * @param destClass The destination class
 * @return The cost of transforming an object
 */
private static float getObjectTransformationCost(Class srcClass, Class destClass) {
    System.out.println("----------- start calculate cost from " + srcClass + " to " + destClass + "------------");

    float cost = 0.0f;
    while (destClass != null && !destClass.equals(srcClass)) {
        System.out.println(srcClass + " and " + destClass + " are " + (destClass.equals(srcClass)? " equal" : " not equal"));
        if (destClass.isInterface() && isAssignmentCompatible(destClass,srcClass)) {
            // slight penalty for interface match. 
            // we still want an exact match to override an interface match, but  
            // an interface match should override anything where we have to get a 
            // superclass.
            cost += 0.25f;
            break;
        }
        cost++;

        destClass = destClass.getSuperclass();
    }

    /*
     * If the destination class is null, we've travelled all the way up to 
     * an Object match. We'll penalize this by adding 1.5 to the cost.
     */
    if (destClass == null) {
        cost += 1.5f;
    }
    System.out.println("COST IS " + cost);


    return cost;
}
```

so output is

```
--- setters:
setData x
setData y
setData y
--- invokeMethod
----------- start calculate cost from class Lolka$DataZ to class Lolka$DataX------------
class Lolka$DataZ and class Lolka$DataX are  not equal
class Lolka$DataZ and class java.lang.Object are  not equal
COST IS 3.5
----------- start calculate cost from class Lolka$DataZ to class Lolka$DataY------------
class Lolka$DataZ and class Lolka$DataY are  not equal
class Lolka$DataZ and class Lolka$DataX are  not equal
class Lolka$DataZ and class java.lang.Object are  not equal
COST IS 4.5
setData x
```

So invokeMethode assumes that converting DataX is only one inheritance-level form Object, and DataY is 2. So DataX-method is "cheaper". Thats the logic behind that.

**UPD:**
changing dest to src works fine, so if i use

```
private static float getObjectTransformationCost(Class srcClass, Class destClass) {
    float cost = 0.0f;
    while (srcClass != null && !destClass.equals(srcClass)) {
        if (destClass.isInterface() && isAssignmentCompatible(destClass,srcClass)) {
            cost += 0.25f;
            break;
        }
        cost++;

        srcClass = srcClass.getSuperclass();
    }

    if (srcClass == null) {
        cost += 1.5f;
    }

    return cost;
}
```

the output is

```
--- setters:
setData x
setData y
setData y
--- invokeMethod
setData y
```