# Java reflection finding method

Tags: java, reflection

I have a problem with finding a method with Java, for example, I have to print a value to System.out via reflection:

```
public static void print(Object value) {
    Method method = PrintStream.class.getMethod("print", value.getClass());
    method.invoke(System.out, value);
}
```

It works fine with strings, but when I pass an instance of `MyClass`, for example, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.io.PrintStream.print(MyClass)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at Test.print(Test.java:20)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

I believe that's because Java cannot find the method with the exact signature, but here `java.io.PrintStream.print(java.lang.Object)` suits well. How can I find a method that suits the following classes, not just has the same signature? The approach should also work for multiple arguments.

Comment: so you want to find all `print` methods from `PrintStream` ?

Comment: no, that's just an example, see the last "paragraph"

Comment: This is unclear.

Comment: If you write method.invoke(System.out, value.toString()); it should print for all types of classes.

Comment: Is there some cogent reason why you don't just write `System.out.print(value);`? What exactly do you think you're gaining?

Comment: @Sambit Unless `value` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe that's because Java cannot find the method with the exact signature ...

That is correct.  The reflection APIs don't support this.  There is no simple way to replicate Java's (static) method overload resolution when looking up a method reflectively.

The non-simple way is to:

1. Identify all of the classes and interfaces that `MyClass` implements.  (You can do that reflectively.)
2. Call `PrintStream.class.getMethod("print", type)` for each of those class / interface types.
3. If you get more than one result from step 2, use some heuristic to work out which method is the "best" one to use.  (It doesn't have to be one that mirrors what the JLS does, though that would probably be the "least surprising" approach to use.)

There are 3rd party libraries that will do this for you; look at this Q&As for some suggestions:

- [Getting the best fit Instance Method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110579/getting-the-best-fit-instance-method-in-java)

Comment: Why? All the overloads except `print(String)` are going to call `print(String.valueOf(value))` one way or the other. There is nothing to be gained by using reflection here.

Comment: This is not a comment on my answer, and (IMO) it is not a legitimate comment on the question. It is clear to me that `PrintStream.print` is just an example.  The fact that it is not a *realistic* example is not relevant.