# Compiler-like Java Reflection method resolution

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

I'm programming a method that uses Reflection to find methods the "same way" (not exactly, as you will see) the compiler does. I left Generics out of the scope in this case, as the type parameter does not affect signature of methods (as far as I know).

**Basically I want to ask how far are my methods from accomplishing the task in a relatively acceptable way (I don't expect perfect and full resolution, I don't even need static methods).**

I could not find the exact spects about how does the compiler actually perform the task, so I made a guess that **suits the needs of my environment**, however, if possible and not too complex, I'd like to have it done in the proper way for possible complex future uses.

Right now, my assumption is IGNORING overloaded methods with different return types, as it is not a problem with my current problem, but that may be in the future, so I may be interested in taking it into consideration if you have ideas.

So, as I don't have to care about return types, I start by calling a simple

```
clazz.getMethods();
```

and then I perform a filter by name. I'm aware I'm totally missing the overrides mentioned abvove here. This is a first approach.

This is how I calculate the distance between a method and the desired arguments:
If parent and children are the same instance, then the distance is 0. If not, this methods calls classDistance recursively on children superclass and all directly implemented interfaces. The distance will be the smalles positive distance plus one. (ignoring incompatible ancestors). This solution works for me because right now all the functions I need to call have just one parameter, and the few that have a second one, allways do a perfect match on first parameter on the desired method, so there's only one positive distance to narrow down.

Actual code:

```
private static Method getBestMatch(List<Method> validMethods, List<Class<?>> classes) {
    if(validMethods.size() == 1) return validMethods.get(0);
    int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Method currMethod = null;
    outer_loop:
    for(Method method : validMethods) {
        Class<?>[] methodTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        int methodDistance = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < methodTypes.length; i++) {
            if(!methodTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(classes.get(i))) continue outer_loop; // Incompatible. Should not happen, but just in case
            methodDistance += classDistance(methodTypes[i], classes.get(i));

        }
        if(currMethod == null || methodDistance < distance) {
            currMethod = method;
            distance = methodDistance;
        }
    }
    return currMethod;
}
```

Distance calculator:

```
private static int classDistance(Class<?> parent, Class<?> children) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(parent.equals(children)) return 0;
    if(!parent.isAssignableFrom(children)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("children is not assignable to father"); // Should do b4 equals?
    Integer minDistance = null;

    Class<?> superClass = children.getSuperclass();
    if(superClass != null && parent.isAssignableFrom(superClass)) {
        minDistance = classDistance(parent, superClass);
    }
    for(Class<?> directInterface : children.getInterfaces()) {
        if(!parent.isAssignableFrom(directInterface)) continue;
        int interfaceDistance = classDistance(parent, directInterface);
        if(interfaceDistance < minDistance)  minDistance = interfaceDistance;
    }

    if(minDistance == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("we found no distance. this is an odd behaviour and definetly a bug, or means this method is not well-thought at all");
    return minDistance + 1;
}
```

Things I should take into consideration:

- Should I complain about ambigous methods? As you can see I just pick up the first
- That overloaded with different type issue... How can I know precedence? If I'm not wrong, compiler allways picks the method of the closest class.
- That distance calculation looks too simple to be true

Comment: Request for a library specifically off topic here.  Off the top of my head I don't know of any such library.

Comment: @markspace I've removed that request from the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DGoiko Can you describe in one sentence **what** you're solving for/the problem/requirement you're addressing? This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: I need a non-programmer to be able to call arbitrary Class methods using a web interface to configure, using some short of block-building languaje. I'll later compile their blocks and cache the methods obtained using Reflection in the compilation phase.

User is not expected to know about method overloading and things like that, and it not expected to cast Integer to Number to explicitly define the method they want.  They can define their own variable scope and perform simple baked operations, but sometimes they need to access actual arbitrary functions of their stored instances. @ernest_k

Comment: Will all the methods be provided by a single class?

Comment: So i need something dynamic enough to not require programming skills to figure out problems, but deterministic and close enough to code so an actuall programmer who knows Java but has no special knowledge of the framework can review a script and detect problems derived of strong typing

Comment: @ernest_k I'm not sure If I understand. If you ask if the methods to find allways come from same class, no, it can virtually be any Java class. If you're asking about implementation, this is part of a Utils class that will be used by the actual objects doing the compilation and run emulations. That Class comes from an arbitrary instance getClass() method.

Comment: So your going to allow a web interface to call any arbitrary class and method on your class path?  This sounds like the biggest security nightmare since Active X.

Comment: @markspace No. There's a SecurityManager that filters out configurations to DAOs previously approved by programmers. It is not meant for the Internet, anyway, but the system needs to be complete enough to do not need internal modifications to include DAOs that are more complex than expected.

Comment: Then you'd be better off to filter those calls by design, and put the calls on specific classes that can be handled specially by the code.  I think that's what ernest was getting at.

Comment: @markspace That's what I did with 99% of the statements, however, there's a small percent of them that require this kind of freedom. I've had all those concerns myself before. I thought the thread could derive on this fact, and that's why I didn't mention the problem I was trying to solve first.

Comment: Just for your info, this function is used in a single method, createInstance, which has to invoke an arbitrary DAO instance. Parameters and DAO name are filtered server-side to prevent an attacker to modify working configurations into malicious code, but I can't foresee the complexity of constructors, and I don't want to force programmers to write and maintain complex configuration files to sync their DAOs, unless they want to (function which is provided in a less-flexible operation that can be subclassed to instance SPECIFIC instances, never allowing the user to name'em.

Comment: And using this feature will be marked with the appropiate catastrophic warnings. And there's a "safer" function that onyl executes methods if the passed instance implements a specific Interface created for this, or a custom one defined by the user.

Comment: If I were you, I would use a dynamic language that has been designed to do this kind of runtime linking. Implementing this on your own will be quite an exercise.

Comment: tbh, I was bored. I also wanted direct Java integration. I know this would've been much easier with, ie, python, but my main purpose if this goes somewhere is integration with Java services such as Lucene or Nutch, so I decided to use Java. The web interface was just an example of configuration tool, I hate interface designing so I made a simple HTML + JS local page to generate my testing JSONs in an easy way. This is not meant for people to be able to do "anything", it is mostly aimed to rich / plain text processing, but some complex functions are required to return Objects instead of text

Comment: and for those cases I decided to enable the requested dangerous function. Most poeple will never use it, in my case I'm providing my test subjects with functions already baked that hide those complex thought from them, so they can just define what they want to do with the text they're processing. On the other side, if this is actually used by programmers, there are some Reflection based functions that would allow them to do virtually anything, as they're assumed to be trusted parts (they could put malicious code into the companies code anyway without this).

Comment: So all this trouble comes because in Alpha, during one of the tests for those functions, the thing was not able to infer passing ArrayList to foo(List) was actually legal, and marked it as non-compilable, so I wanted to give programmers the closest experience than when directly using Java. It may be a bit stupid, and you're definetly right that other languajes would fit the task better, but I don't need complex things like lambdas, and I wanted to enforce type safety on the output of the program in order to directly match Java DAOs so... here we are xD

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110714/294657

Comment: Are you fine with `List<Class<?>> classes`? As types might be generic like parameter type might be `List<? extends String>` so just matching to `List` might not be valid.

Answer (score 3):

> I could not find the exact spects about how does the compiler actually perform the task

They are in the [**Java Language Specification**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), section [15.12. Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), more precisely in subsection [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).

It's quite complex, and as you can see, far more involved than what you're currently trying to do.

I'll leave it up to you to read through all of sections 15.12.2 to 15.12.2.6, and then determine how much you can ignore and still *"accomplishing the task in a relatively acceptable way"*.

Comment: I can ignore most of those, like variable artity, lambdas and so on, but this was helpfull. Will come back to mark as accepted in a couple days so this can still be seen

Answer (score 0):

Note that compiler does not work on just classes like your current code, but it works on full types, depending what kind of code you are writing it might affect you. Imagine this:

```
void someMethod(List<? extends Number> numbers);
void someMethod(Collection<String> numbers);
```

Then if you will look for method that can accept `ArrayList` you will find both, so if you don't know type of your data, you will not be able to provide valid answer. But generic type of variables is lost anyway, so if you are trying to find matching method for some list of arguments - you can't do that in good reliable way.

```
Object[] args = new Object[]{List.of("String")};
Class[] argTypes = extractTypes(args); // contains [SomeListImplementation.class]
findBestMatchingMethod(SomeClass.class, argTypes); // ?? both method matches
```

You could try to "rebuild" generic type by analyzing what is inside object, but that is very hard and would not always work (because raw types are used or object is empty). Would only be kinda possible for collection types to some limited degree.

But if this is enough, then java have some tools for this:

```
new Statement(object, "doSomething", new Object[]{arg1, arg2, arg3}).execute();
```

But return value is lost. But you can just copy code from jdk used to do this. I also once developed my own code to do something like that:

First we need some utils we will use later, like easy way to map between primitive and object types, as java compiler handles this for us, so we should too:

```
public final class ClassUtils {
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> primitives = Map.of(
        Boolean.class,   boolean.class,     Byte.class,    byte.class,        Short.class, short.class,
        Character.class, char.class,        Integer.class, int.class,         Long.class,  long.class,
        Float.class,     float.class,       Double.class,  double.class,      Void.class,  void.class);
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> wrappers   = Map.of(
        boolean.class, Boolean.class,       byte.class,   Byte.class,         short.class, Short.class,
        char.class,    Character.class,     int.class,    Integer.class,      long.class,  Long.class,
        float.class,   Float.class,         double.class, Double.class,       void.class,  Void.class);

    public static Class<?> getPrimitive(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz.isPrimitive()) {
            return clazz;
        }
        return primitives.getOrDefault(clazz, clazz);
    }

    public static Class<?> getWrapperClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (! clazz.isPrimitive()) {
            return clazz;
        }
        return wrappers.getOrDefault(clazz, clazz);
    }
}
```

And simple util to check if object of typeA could be assigned to typeB but handling primitive types (as in java you can pass `int` to `long`, or `int` to `Integer`) too:

```
public final class TypeUtils {
    private TypeUtils() {}

    /**
     * Checks if given objectType can be assigned to variable of variableType type.
     *
     * @param objectType type of object that you want to assign.
     * @param variableType type of variable where object will be assigned.
     * @param autoboxing whether to use implicit autoboxing/unboxing between primitives and wrappers
     *
     * @return {@code true} if assignment possible
     */
    public static boolean isAssignable(@Nullable Class<?> objectType, final Class<?> variableType, final boolean autoboxing) {
        if (objectType == null) {
            return ! variableType.isPrimitive();
        }
        if (objectType == variableType) {
            return true;
        }

        if (autoboxing) {
            if (objectType.isPrimitive() && ! variableType.isPrimitive()) {
                objectType = ClassUtils.getWrapperClass(objectType);
            }
            if (variableType.isPrimitive() && ! objectType.isPrimitive()) {
                objectType = ClassUtils.getPrimitive(objectType);
                if (! objectType.isPrimitive()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (objectType == variableType) {
            return true;
        }

        if (objectType.isPrimitive()) {
            if (! variableType.isPrimitive()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (Integer.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return Long.TYPE.equals(variableType) || Float.TYPE.equals(variableType) || Double.TYPE.equals(variableType);
            }
            if (Long.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return Float.TYPE.equals(variableType) || Double.TYPE.equals(variableType);
            }
            if (Boolean.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (Double.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (Float.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return Double.TYPE.equals(variableType);
            }
            if (Character.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return Integer.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Long.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Float.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Double.TYPE.equals(variableType);
            }
            if (Short.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return Integer.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Long.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Float.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Double.TYPE.equals(variableType);
            }
            if (Byte.TYPE.equals(objectType)) {
                return Short.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Integer.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Long.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Float.TYPE.equals(variableType)
                               || Double.TYPE.equals(variableType);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return variableType.isAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

Note: if you will be trying to make version that works with generics, apache commons have method to check if 2 generic types are assignable to each other, as I would not suggest writing it alone, its a lot of complicated code to handle all possible nested generic types.

And having these 2 simple utils we can start creating code to find this matching executable, first I made small enum to represent 3 possible states of method:

```
enum CompatibleExecutableResult {
    EXACT,
    COMPATIBLE,
    INVALID
}
```

It can either be perfect match or be compatible or no match, we have separate exact match because javac would then fail to compile due to ambiguous definitions, so we probably 
 want to do the same.

So now a simple function that calculates that:

```
private static CompatibleExecutableResult isCompatibleExecutable(Method method, Class[] providedTypes) {
    Class<?>[] constructorParameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    CompatibleExecutableResult current = CompatibleExecutableResult.EXACT;
    for (int i = 0; i < constructorParameterTypes.length; i++) {
        Class<?> providedType = providedTypes[i];
        Class<?> parameterType = constructorParameterTypes[i];

        // null can't be used as primitive
        if ((providedType == null) && parameterType.isPrimitive()) {
            return CompatibleExecutableResult.INVALID;
        }

        // handle primitives correctly by using our special util function
        if ((providedType != null) && !TypeUtils.isAssignable(parameterType, providedType, true)) {
            return CompatibleExecutableResult.INVALID;
        }

        // this code support skipping some types assuming that you will use null value for it, so you can look for any method with 3 arguments where you only know 2 first types and last one will be always null.
        if ((providedType == null)) {
            current = CompatibleExecutableResult.COMPATIBLE;
            continue;
        }

        if (parameterType.equals(providedType)) {
            continue; // sill exact match
        }
        // it was not an exact match as types of this argument were not equals, so thats our current max possible score for this method
        current = CompatibleExecutableResult.COMPATIBLE;
    }
    return current;
}
```

But now we could find few exact matches, or few compatible methods, so we also need a function that will tell us which method is more specialized:

```
static Method getMoreSpecialized(Method a, Method b) {
    if (a == null) return b;
    if (b == null) return a;
    Class<?>[] aTypes = a.getParameterTypes();
    Class<?>[] bTypes = b.getParameterTypes();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aTypes.length; i++) {
        Class<?> aType = aTypes[i];
        Class<?> bType = bTypes[i];

        // same type, no differences so far
        if (aType.equals(bType)) {
            continue;
        }

        // if aType is less specialized than bType
        if ((aType.isPrimitive() && !bType.isPrimitive()) || TypeUtils.isAssignable(aType, bType, true)) {
            // one of prev types was less specialized, javac fails to find such constructor, we should too
            if (result < 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Ambiguous executables found for: " + Arrays.toString(aTypes) + " and " + Arrays.toString(bTypes));
            }
            result += 1;
        } else {
            if (result > 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Ambiguous executables found for: " + Arrays.toString(aTypes) + " and " + Arrays.toString(bTypes));
            }
            result -= 1;
        }
    }
    if (result == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Ambiguous executables found for: " + Arrays.toString(aTypes) + " and " + Arrays.toString(bTypes));
    }
    return result < 0 ? a : b;
}
```

And then we can write our simple loop that will find best match, so loop over methods, check if compatible and check if more specialized than last one + be sure to not allow more than 1 exact match:

```
static <T> Method findBest(Collection<? extends Method> methods, Class[] paramTypes) {
    int exactMatches = 0;
    Method bestMatch = null;
    for (Method executable : methods) {
        CompatibleExecutableResult compatibleConstructor = isCompatibleExecutable(executable, paramTypes);
        if (compatibleConstructor == CompatibleExecutableResult.EXACT) {
            if (exactMatches >= 1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Ambiguous executables found " + Arrays.toString(paramTypes));
            }
            exactMatches += 1;
        }
        if (compatibleConstructor != CompatibleExecutableResult.INVALID) {
            bestMatch = getMoreSpecialized(bestMatch, executable);
        }
    }
    if (bestMatch == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't find matching executable for: " + Arrays.toString(paramTypes));
    }
    return bestMatch;
}
```

Code supporting generic types should look similar, just use `Type[]` and that apache commons method to check if objects are assignable with a small wrapper to also handle primitive types correctly like here.